# Javascript - Replace all strings in page that begin with

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm hitting a wall.
I'm trying to replace all strings in a page that start with "Person 1" by "Person 1 (ValueFromPreviousField)".

I'm unable to apply the *replace whole string that **starts with** 'Person 1'* logic, so every time I hit update button, the previous "(ValueFromPreviousField)" stays at the end of the string (which I obviously don't want).

```
function test() {
  var N1 = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
        var N2 = document.getElementById("Name2").value;
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Person 1 */g, "Person 1 (" + N1 +")").replace(/Person 2/g, "Person 2 (" + N2 +")");

}
```

Here is a fiddle with a sample html: http://jsfiddle.net/ndt50xgo/20/

PS: Since this is html generated by a shortcode, I can't assign classes or id's to all of those spans.

Comment: I think you'll find that you'll lose your input values every time you change `document.body.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this: if you start with `x y` and you replace `x` with `x a`, you end up with `x a y`. Now, if you replace `x` with `x b` after that, you end up with `x b a y`, since there is nothing causing your text to revert back to `x y` first. The same applies to your example. Your regex should also match any text you added to make sure it gets replaced as well.

So, instead of `/Person 1 */g` it could have `/Person 1( \(.*?\))?/g` and for `/Person 2 */g` of course `/Person 2( \(.*?\))?/g`.

Comment: THIS. It works exactly as intended. I had tried the `\(.*?\))` part but obviously incorrectly since I was in a fishing expedition. I'll look more into that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tools like RegexBuddy or sites like https://regex101.com/ (no affiliation, I just like them) can be a great help to write more complicated regular expressions. You're welcome!

Comment: Just a note of warning, as I was suggesting the same thing but since it was so similar I deleted: note that this causes improper behaviour if the name contains a closing parenthesis. By its very nature, `.*?` stops after the first positive match, so in case of a name with a parenthesis in it (either malicious or not), the code will stop working. You should probably match up to a closing tag, to be safer.

Comment: @Varstahl is correct, but note that JavaScript does not support recursive matching, so the perfect solution of counting parentheses is not available, you should look for non-regex solutions there. The only regex solution, if your names could indeed include parentheses, is to match to something else at the end of the match (like a closing tag), that would never show up in a name, or you could write a more complicated regex that would match up to two levels of nested parentheses, but I would recommend against that.

Comment: The most stupid solution, if the name includes parenthesis, would be to encode `)` into `&#41;` before replacing it in the document. Problem solved.

Comment: I don't need to use parenthesis, I could use basically anything to separate Person x from the name. Even just a hyphen in between. What would be your suggestion? Thank you both!

Comment: @Varstahl made the best suggestion initially, by suggesting you use html tags to surround and select the appropriate bit of text, if you're doing it this way. I would only remark that applying a regular expression to the whole document body is not the recommended way to approach this problem, you might want to consider using JavaScript commands that allow you to navigate the document object model and replace the content of that tag directly.